# Whenever I try to run this php file this file show error

Tags: sql-insert

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrXWJ.jpg)Parse error :syntax error

Comment: Please help me your help is very helpful in  my final year project

Comment: You _will_ need to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with code, and _not_ in a screenshot.